# Getting the text of an inner span 

Tags: javascript

if i have the following links :

```
    <a href="#" onclick="return navigateTo(this)" id="menuList:0:menu" class="normalLink">
        <span id="menulist:0:menuLabel">
            <span > Main Page </span>
        </span>
    </a>        
    
    <a href="#" onclick="return navigateTo(this)" id="menuList:1:menu" class="normalLink">
        <span id="menulist:1:menuLabel">
            <span > Search Orders </span>
        </span>
    </a>
    
    <a href="#" onclick="return navigateTo(this)" id="menuList:2:menu" class="selectedLink">
        <span id="menulist:2:menuLabel">
            <span > Orders History </span>
        </span>
    </a>
```

I want to get the element which has the class name `selectedLink` and then get the value of the inner `span` of that element where it says in above example `Order History`.

I can do the first part of finding the element which has `selectedLink` class, but i cannot retrive the text inside the inner span of that element. Below is my code to find the element with class `selectedLink`:

```
    var elem = this.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) 
    {
        var classes = elem[i].className;
        if(classes == 'selectedLink' ){
            alert("ok found it the selected link");
        }
    }
```

Can anyone suggest a way to retrieve `Order History`? Thanks

### UPDATE: Follow up question

So the point of this excerise is that, i wanted to add a check where if the page is "Order History" yet the navigation menu had `selectedLink` style applied to another page (happens when user presses BACK) i wanted JavaScript logic to fix the problem so below is my code:

```
            //get the element that has "selectedLink" style
           // if the text says "Order History" then style is applied ok  
           var elems =  document.getElementsByClassName("selectedLink");
           if(typeof elems != "undefined"){
               for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
                   alert(elems.length);
                   var text = elems[i].innerText || elems[i].textContent;
                   alert(text);
                   if(text == "Order History"){
                       alert("its ok");
                   }
                   else { //we're here because the element that has "selectedLink" style in not "order History"
                   
                        //get all elements that have "normalLink" style and see which one is "Order History"
                       var allLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("normalLink");
                       for(var j = 0; j < allLinks.length; j++ ){
                           var curText = allLinks[j].innerText || allLinks[j].textContent;
                          
                           if(curText == "Order History"){
                               alert("there it is at counter " + j);
                               alert(allLinks[j].innerText);
                               
                               //swap the class names
                               allLinks[j].className = "selectedLink";
                               elems[i].className = "normalLink";
                               break;
                           }
                       }
                   }
                }
            }
```

The changing class names bit isn't working! Am i doing it wrong?

### UPDATE 2:

Fixed, It was my silly mistake :

changed the ordering of the following :

```
    allLinks[j].className = "selectedLink";
    elems[i].className = "normalLink";
```

to:

```
    elems[i].className = "normalLink";
    allLinks[j].className = "selectedLink";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, just use `getElementsByClassName()` to get the element, that saves you a huge amount of effort:

```
var link = document.getElementsByClassName("selectedLink")[0]; // new browsers only
var link = document.querySelector(".selectedLink"); // more support, but not in IE7 or lower
var link = $(".selectedLink"); // with jQuery
```

Then, since that text is the only text, you can just use `textContent` (`innerText` in older IE)

Your end code is one of these, depending on your target browsers and if you have a framework or not:

```
var text = link.textContent; // new browsers
var text = link.innerText || link.textContent; // older browers
var text = link.text(); // jQuery
```

Comment: Depending on the browser support requirement, `document.querySelector()` could work.

Comment: Thanks, so which should i be using to guarantee IE 7 compatibility and that also works in chrome?

Comment: jQuery is "easiest", really, otherwise you do have to shim `getElementsByClassName` which is basically what you have already.

Comment: @Kolink can you please comment on the updated question please?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect job for jquery. include the jquery library on your page, then use the following code:

```
var text = $('.selectedLink').first('span').first('span').html();
```

Comment: jQuery is not indicated on this question, and suggesting it in cases where it's a simple task oftentimes ends in downvotes. FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var elem = this.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) 
{
    var classes = elem[i].className;
    if(classes == 'selectedLink' ){
        alert("ok found it the selected link");
        var a = elem[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[1].innerHTML;
        alert(a);
    }
}
```

**JSBin**
http://jsbin.com/epoxej/edit#preview